# Show CSS property in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to show style `display: none` property in javascript.

This is my code:

```
switch(aa){
 case 1:
   $value="<input type=text id='myid' value=''/>";
   display = none;              
   break;
}
```

I want to show this when some conditions are true, but I cannot display this.

This is my javascript function:

```
function x(){
  if(condition){
    $("#id").show();     
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this to display ..

```
function x(){
  if(condition){
    document.getElementById("myid").style.display="block";
  }
}
```

and for making display none you can do this..

```
$value="<input type=text id='myid' value='' style='display:none'/>";
```

Comment: Closing `}` for the function and go ahead and add the `;` inside the if statement so you don't confuse devuser.

Comment: I changed my code according to your answer.but still I can not show this

Comment: function x(){
  var select_moneywork = document.getElementById('{$thi>htmlID_moneyworkID}');
var select_value = select_moneywork.options[select_moneywork.selectedIndex].value;alert(select_value);
if(select_value == 'bbb' )
   {
    document.getElementById("id").style.display="block";
  }
}

Comment: yes I checked this.but when clicking on the button nothing shows.text field is not visible at all I want to show that field when clicking on the button

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Nt2SS/1/ now check this out.. it will first show a button alone after clicking the button.It will display a textbox with "hai.."

Comment: If u want to see result alone check this http://jsfiddle.net/Nt2SS/1/embedded/result/

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your styling inside the input element.

```
$value="<input type=text id='myid' style='display:none' value=''/>";
```

Comment: I added style='display:none' but it is still not working